# how to check socket is not receiving for a time period

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

In my application two different sockets are receiving and sending periodic data. I need to close the socket if it does not receive or send for a particular time period. Since I am using continuously flowing periodic data, i could not previously set the number of send and receive. Please help me to find out a way that the socket is not receiving or sending for a time period

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Also please include any research or attempts made thus far to try and solve the issue at hand.

Comment: You can use `select` to wait for I/O on your sockets: it accepts a max time period to wait, so if when it returns there's no indication of expected I/O activity, you can close the sockets involved....  Look at the man page and google some examples, write your code, and if you get stuck come back here with your code and specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set a read timeout on the socket with SO_RCVTIMEO. If it expires, `recv()` will return -1 with `errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`.